# Is it "there was" or "there were?"

Tags: verbs

I think "were" is the right answer, but still I want an opinion on this. So is it "was" or "were" in the sentence given below?

> There ...... only fifty rupees in my pocket.

Answer (score 1):

'Was' is wrong grammar.

The sentence should be

> There were only fifty rupees in my pocket.